# Find an Element using find function in parent tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a dynamic select box but when I click each `.option` tag its title place in all select-show in entire page.

I want it to just be placed in the `.select-show` element that is exactly in the same parent `.selectbox` tag and not the others.

```js
$(".option").click(function() {
  let selectBoxShow = $(this).parent().find(".select").find(".select-shows");
  let optionTitle = $(this).find(".option-title").text();
  selectBoxShow.text(optionTitle);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<div class="selectbox w-50 mb-5">
  <div class="select">
    <div>
      <i class="fa-light fa-grid-2"></i>
      <span class="select-shows">Select your City</span>
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
  </div>
  <menu class="options">
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-container">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i><span class="option-title">Whitehorse</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-container">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i><span class="option-title">Yellowknife</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-container">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i><span class="option-title">Regina</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-container">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i><span class="option-title">Winnipeg</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-container">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i><span class="option-title">Charlottetown</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </menu>
</div>
```

Comment: The parent of all your `.option` elements is `menu.options`, and there is no `.select` to find in there. You should use `parents()` to go up to the actual `.selectbox` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in your code is due to the use of `find()`. This is intended to traverse the DOM to find a matching *child* element. In your case you need to find the *sibling* to the `parent()` of the clicked `.option`.

There's a few ways to fix this issue.

- Use `closest()` to get the nearest common parent, then `find()`:
  `$(this).closest('.selectbox').find('.select-shows')`
- Use `parent()` then `prev()` to get the previous sibling:
  `$(this).parent().prev('.select-shows')`.

My preference is to use `closest()` as it's more robust, and won't be broken by a simple HTML change. Here's a working example of this fix:

```js
$(".option").click(function() {
  const $option = $(this);
  const selectBoxShow = $option.closest('.selectbox').find(".select .select-shows");
  const optionTitle = $option.find(".option-title").text();
  selectBoxShow.text(optionTitle);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectbox w-50 mb-5">
  <div class="select">
    <div>
      <i class="fa-light fa-grid-2"></i>
      <span class="select-shows">Select your City</span>
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
  </div>
  <menu class="options">
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-container">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i><span class="option-title">Whitehorse</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-container">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i><span class="option-title">Yellowknife</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-container">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i><span class="option-title">Regina</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-container">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i><span class="option-title">Winnipeg</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-container">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i><span class="option-title">Charlottetown</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </menu>
</div>

<div class="selectbox w-50 mb-5">
  <div class="select">
    <div>
      <i class="fa-light fa-grid-2"></i>
      <span class="select-shows">Select your City</span>
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
  </div>
  <menu class="options">
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-container">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i><span class="option-title">Whitehorse</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-container">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i><span class="option-title">Yellowknife</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-container">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i><span class="option-title">Regina</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-container">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i><span class="option-title">Winnipeg</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-container">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i><span class="option-title">Charlottetown</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </menu>
</div>
```